# Escape asterisk in shell script

Tags: bash

The asterisk sign in the below array is getting expanded into the list of files when assigning it to an array.

```
u='*','john'
IFS=$',';q=($u)
for j in "${!q[@]}"
do
        echo "drop user ${q[j]}"
done
```

The output is:

```
drop user abc
drop user test.sh
drop user test1.sh
drop user john
```

What I intend to get is:

```
drop user *
drop user john
```

How can I escape the asterisk?

Comment: Looks like you're using `bash` here. If that is so then better to add `bash` tag in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this script:

```
u='*,john'

# read comma delimited string into an array
IFS=, read -ra q <<< "$u"

# check content of array q
declare -p q

# loop through array q
for j in "${q[@]}"
do
    echo "drop user $j"
done
```

**Output:**

```
declare -a q=([0]="*" [1]="john")
drop user *
drop user john
```

Comment: While q is already an array, what is the line 'declare -p q' for?

Also, what is the difference between parsing the string list using 'IFS=, read -ra q <<< "$u"' and 'IFS=$',';q=($u)'? Why is the former working and not the later?

Comment: `declare -p q` is for printing variable named `q`. `q=($u)` has `$u` unquoted hence it is subject to wildcard expansion hence `*` is expanded by shell.

Comment: But when I want to split the array using newline. Only the first item is getting added to the hostArray. But the host has 4 items.

`host=$(mysql -S $socket $catalog --skip-column-names -e "select host from mysql.user); echo "Host: $host"; IFS=$'\n';read -ra hostArray <<< "$host"; echo "HostArray:$hostArray" #This prints only 1 item. But there are 4 items;`

Comment: But this problem is about splitting on comma. To split on newline use ` mapfile` command.